# How to use replace() function in Python for this situation?

Tags: python, replace

The situation is that we have 4,3,4,3 respectively. If we only want to correct 4 at index 20 to be 3.5. What should the third parameter be?

```
name = "Land grade 4 year 3 4 members at building 4"
print(name.replace(("4","3.5",?))
```

The result that I want -> "Land grade 4 year 3 3.5 member at building 4"

Comment: slice string and replace only on the slice that interests you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slice string and replace only on the slice that interests you, rebuild string.

```
>>> s = "Land grade 4 year 3 4 members at building 4"
>>> s[0:20]+s[20:24].replace("4","3.5")+s[24:]
'Land grade 4 year 3 3.5 members at building 4'
```

maybe slightly better with only 1 replacement, which avoids a string slice:

```
>>> s[0:20]+s[20:].replace("4","3.5",1)
'Land grade 4 year 3 3.5 members at building 4'
```

But if you know exactly where the number to be replaced is, maybe that's because you could just do that with a template string.

```
s = "Land grade 4 year 3 {} members at building 4"
s.format(3.5)
```